# SQL Query on jsp file using Text Box Search and button

Tags: sql, jsp, jstl

I have a difficulty in the search(select sql statement). How to put the value I inputed in the text box and use it in the sql query
so that I can search the department name regarding to the value I inserted.

I don't know the right Query for this "SELECT * FROM department where department_name ='"%search%"'"

Here is my jsp file below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR" pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
 /head>


 <body>

       <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/department"
     user="root"  password="root"/>

 <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="sql">
SELECT * from department;
<!-- SELECT * FROM department where department_name ='"%search%"'-->
</sql:query>

  <FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST">
  <input type="text" name="search"/>
   <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Button 1">
   </FORM><br>


    <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>department Id</th>
                <th>department Name</th>

                <th colspan=1>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${sql.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.department_id}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.department_name}" /></td>
                  </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the first paragraph: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html In other words, every sane JSP developer in the world sincerely hopes that you're not using this in production.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the fist, insert paramerer into you SQL query

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="sql">
SELECT * from department WHERE department_name = <%= request.getParameter("query") %>;
</sql:query>
```

Change method to METHOD="GET" and

```
<input type="text" name="query"/>
<INPUT TYPE="submit">
```

When you click button, url was like

http://hostname.com/mywebapp/mypage.jsp?query=John+Smith

Comment: Thanks now I can use the value of from the text box. but I have another problem
When I Tried using:

`SELECT * from department WHERE department_name = <%= request.getParameter("query") %>;`

an error appearing that:
**java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'Math' in 'where clause'**
It searches the column name but not the data inside the column

Comment: I'll remove the downvote once you fix the severe SQL injection attack hole.